# html.textbox datetime format

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

is it possible to format a text box at page level (not viewmodel) so a datetime can exclude the time stamp?

i cant edit the viewmodel in this project.. so i have to pass in to the view the viewmodel containing a datetime property.

```
<%=Html.TextBox("DateOfBirth", Model.DateOfBirth)%><br />
```

thanks

Comment: Check This: http://www.codingfusion.com/Post/Display-a-formatted-date-in-a-TextBoxFor--in-Asp-Net-MVC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just format your Model.DateOfBirth:

```
<%=Html.TextBox("DateOfBirth", Model.DateOfBirth.ToShortDateString())%>
```